# Vector Indexing in R

Tags: r

I am calculating how many consecutive 0s or 1s in a sequence of 10 numbers.
For example 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
There are 4 (00, 11, 11, 11).

Here is my code.

```
c <- floor(2 * runif(10))
count = 0

for (i in 1:length(c)) {
        a = c[i] 
        b = c[i+1]
        if (a == b) {
             count = count + 1
    }
    count
    }
```

Error:   Error in if (a == b) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thank you.

Comment: At the end of your loop, `b` is `c[length(c) + 1]` which will return `NA` because you are trying to access the 11th number in a vector of length 10.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rle` :

```
with(rle(x), sum(lengths[lengths > 1] - 1))
#[1] 4
```

**data**

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```